# Powershell convert Collection? to list?

Tags: powershell, select-object

I'm trying to parse Palo Alto firewall rules with Powershell. Some rules can have ~100 servernames in them. I need to break down each name to check if they're still alive (DNS) and return rule mapping for each servername. Most of it works except for:

Currently I have:

```
RuleName, {Hostname1;Hostname2;Hostname3}
```

I'm trying to get:

```
RuleName, Hostname1 ;
RuleName, Hostname2 ;
RuleName, Hostname3
```

I started with a hashtable, but having issues with overall script length - too long

I've been doing:

```
Select-Object RuleName,@{Name="Hostnames";Expression={($_.Hostnames).Split(";")}
```

But feels like I need a `ForEach-Object` in the Expression to add the RuleName field to each hostname, so it doesn't turn into a collection.

Comment: How do you obtain this output? Which cmdlet are you using to get the firewall rules?

Comment: We can't get API, so it's manual download in CSV --> Import-Excel

Answer (score 0):

You need to invert your logic: enumerate the hostnames first, then construct an object for each:

```powershell
foreach ($host in $_.Hostnames.Split(';')) {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    RuleName = $_.RuleName
    Hostname = $host
  }
}
```

Note that in this case it's simpler to use a `[pscustomobject]` literal to construct the output objects, although a [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) solution with [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) (as in your attempt), is possible too:

```powershell
$thisObj = $_
$thisObj.Hostnames.Split(';') |
  Select-Object @{ Name='RuleName'; Expression={ $thisObj.RuleName } }, 
                @{ Name='Hostname'; Expression={ $_ } }
```